# Start a background Service on Backend Server request

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Does anybody know of a good way to start a background service on the request of the mobile applications back-end server?

I am writing a app where i need to run some code on the request of the server.

Comment: You can read the document about [Creating Android Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/). Also have a look at these threads may help: [How can one create a background service](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85233/how-can-one-create-a-background-service-that-is-always-running) and [backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/](https://robgibbens.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/). Add some more specific requirements of your question would be better.

Comment: Well I'm looking for a way to send like a "Request" to the device from my server that'll  Cause the app to run some code in the background